# Flamingo flower (Anthurium) dying: three years on

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, plant-health, diseases

After a few months of neglecting my plants (only watering and not checking for health problems) I noticed the anthurium is not doing too well. The youngest leaves are withering back, and there aren't as many roots as I would expect. There might be root tips coming from the stalks, or at least some sort of bulging formations. Given that the crown seems to be the epicentre of the problem, does this mean the plant is dead? I had some issues with some saintpaulias nearby, where the leaves were stunted and the crown was rosetting like crazy (I have a few clones and this is not typical to this saintpaulia). I threw them away along with the soil, but am wondering if it might have been some sort of disease which spread to the other nearby plants.
Any suggestions are welcome! This plant has survived 3 years in my 'care'; it is the same one as in [this question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/38302/flamingo-flower-anthurium-leaf-discoloration).
[image: Wilted_leaf]

[image: Wilted_centre]
[image: Yellowing_leaf]

[image: Centre_Wilting]
[image: Wilting_underside]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be so many thing causing this, but I don't think that this is caused by a disease. If this was cause from a disease, it would be more serious and there would be many more signs of a oncoming illness, not just from yellowing leaves. Because of the yellowed leaf tips, it may be going through some sort of nutrient deficiency, it may not be getting enough water, getting too much water, or it may have something to do with the roots like a root disease (unlikely) or the roots are too clustered together.

Try to re-pot in into different or newer soil, and make sure that the soil never completely dries out. Get some sort of plant food for leafy plants at a local store or online and give the plant some of it. If it improves, it may just have had a nutrient deficiency.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. My worry is that the leaves are dying from the centre outwards, rather than the old one dying first. If the newest leaf is already crumbling, is there any change of survival?

Comment: I'm sure the plant will survive. The plant may just need to adapt for a little while before any change may happen