# Parlour Palm Browning Leaves

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, plant-health, diseases, palm

I have had this parlor palm for several years, and it has been in this pot for at least 3 years. I fertilize occasionally every 1-2 months. It usually loses a lower leaf every now and then, which is normal. However, over the past two months, it has started browning more severely, with several lower leaves becoming dull brown and the higher leaves turning brown towards the tips and edges. Also, for the first time ever, the 'flower' stalks are withering before becoming ripe. It was nearby the anthurium from [this post](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/61592/flamingo-flower-anthurium-dying-three-years-on) which I disposed of for fear of spreading disease.
Any help/suggestions are welcome!

[image: browning from tips and sides]
[image: weird spot browning]
[image: flower stalks dying]
[image: tips grey and brown]
[image: whole leaf dying]
[image: whole leaf dying]